# Python fetch email

Tags: python, email

I'm getting a weird message body when trying to load some email messages with Python.

My Code:

```
session = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(host_in, port_in)
session.login(login, password)

session.select('Inbox')
_response_status, response_body = session.search(None, '(UNSEEN)')
msg_id_list = response_body[0].split()

result = []
for msg_id in msg_id_list:
    _response_status, response_body = session.fetch(msg_id,
                                                    '(RFC822)')
    print(response_body[0][1].decode('utf-8'))
```

For short messages all works OK. But for some messages I get correct headers, but body looks something like:

```
PGRpdj48c3BhbiBzdHlsZT0iYmFja2dyb3VuZC1jb2xvcjojZmZmZmZmO2NvbG9yOiMwMDAwMDA7
... 20 lines of some chars ...
Pg0KPC9ibG9ja3F1b3RlPg0KPC9ibG9ja3F1b3RlPg0KPC9ibG9ja3F1b3RlPg0KPC9ibG9ja3F1
b3RlPg==
```

(I replaces 20 lines of chars with "... 20 lines of some chars ...")
The body appears the same for different long messages, any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out. The email server for some reason just base64 encodes the body, I don't know yet why. But I can decode messages like this:

```
import base64
base64.b64decode(my_wierd_msg_body_goes_here)
```

Comment: If message body was encoded, there is a messger header saying that.